# c# Winform Series auto renabled

Tags: c#, winforms, series

The problem I am having is after disabling my Series via `series.Enabled = false;` it automatically reverts back to true afterwards (not sure when/where) and thus reappearing on the Chart.

I do not have any code which explicitly sets the Enabled property to true so I would like to know what could be causing this and how to fix it.

I created the Series using the code below

```
//more initializing
series.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
series.YValueType = ChartValueType.UInt32;
chart.Series.Add(series);
```

Comment: 1. Enabled = false is not invisible, it just means users can't do stuff with it anymore. 2. Where is the code where you disable it, or the code around it? These 3 lines are utterly useless. This way we can't help you at all

Comment: Not true. It is the other way round:  __Enabled==true means invisible__. But you still __can do things with it__, e.g. add points etc. - But you are correct that OP needs to search for the reasons himself. There must be a line that either re-enabels or re-creates the Series.

Comment: Looking a t the way you add the series by first creating and then adding it, most likely you don't use a correct reference.. There is no way it will re-enable itself.

Comment: Don''t you mean Enabled == false means invisible. There is not much more I can show, I tried disabling it directly before or after the series being added to the chart. One question though, even if I don't add the Series to the chart, it is still being shown. Is that natural?

Comment: _Enabled == false means invisible._ __Whoops__ yes, a __typo__. _even if I don't add the Series to the chart, it is still being shown_ No. You probably mean the default Series you get when you drop the chart from the tolbox. use Series.Clear() to delete it! (Or the designer) You also get a default ChartArea and a default Legend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think it is the default one. I created the Series as a member variable though?

Comment: Unless you add it to the Series collection of the chart it isn't visible. What is its Name?

Comment: It is just public `Series series {get;set;}`and `series = new Series("test");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was some logic in an external library which periodically refreshes the charts and re-enabling them.